# Linking multiple header files in C

Tags: c, header-files

I'm working on a project that have 4 files: main.c lists.c hash.c structs.c with the respective .h files. 
The problem is that in lists.c I need to link structs.h. 
And it gives me error saying that functions in structs.c are conflicting with the declaration of that function in the structs.h file.

In lists.h I do #include "structs.h and in lists.c I do #include "lists.h"
and I dont get any erros. 
In stucts.c I do #include "structs.h"

lists.h:

```
#include "structs.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct list{
   Instr head;
   struct list *tail;
} *ILIST;

ILIST mkList(Instr, ILIST);
```

lists.c:

```
#include "lists.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

ILIST mkList(Instr n, ILIST l1) {
  ILIST l = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
  l->head = n;
  l->tail = l1;
  return l;
}
```

structs.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum  {START, QUIT, ATRIB, ADD, SUB, MUL, PRINT, READ, IF, GOTO, LABEL} OpKind;
typedef enum {INT_CONST, STRING, EMPTY} ElemKind;

typedef struct{
  ElemKind kind;
  union
  {
    int val;
    char* name;
  }content;
} Elem;
```

structs.c:

```
#include "structs.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
```

I get erros like this

```
In file included from lists.h:1:0,
                 from main.c:3:
structs.h:5:16: error: redeclaration of enumerator ‘START’
 typedef enum  {START, QUIT, ATRIB, ADD, SUB, MUL, PRINT, READ, IF, GOTO, LABEL} OpKind;
                ^~~~~

In file included from main.c:1:0:
structs.h:5:16: note: previous definition of ‘START’ was here
 typedef enum  {START, QUIT, ATRIB, ADD, SUB, MUL, PRINT, READ, IF, GOTO, LABEL} OpKind;
                ^~~~~
```

Comment: you are including "structs.h" multiple times, so the enum is defined multiple times. try `#pragma once` or #ifndef ... #define ... constructs as include guards

Comment: Thanks for the help. But can u explain what ´´´#pragma once``` does?

Comment: The Wikipedia pages on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once and include guards https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard do a better job at explaining this than I could. But basically both approaches prevent including the header files more than once, to avoid repeated definitions.

Comment: OT: regarding: `typedef struct list{
   Instr head;
   struct list *tail;
} *ILIST;`   1) it is poor programming practice to hide a pointer in a `typedef`  2) for flexibility, it is best to define the structure then the `typedef` statement that renames that structure

Comment: OT: When defining a struct, always include a 'tagname' as most debuggers use the tagname to be able to display the fields within the struct

Comment: How does tagname work? How do I define it in a struct? Also can u show me an example of putting the ```typedef``` after the struct? Im kinda new to structs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Header Guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

just include header guards like:

```c
#ifndef __GUARD_STRUCTS__
#define__GUARD_STRUCTS__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum  {START, QUIT, ATRIB, ADD, SUB, MUL, PRINT, READ, IF, GOTO, LABEL} OpKind;
typedef enum {INT_CONST, STRING, EMPTY} ElemKind;

typedef struct{
  ElemKind kind;
  union
  {
    int val;
    char* name;
  }content;
} Elem;

#endif
```

Comment: And which file do I use that?

Comment: You will say to compiler if __GUARD_STRUCTS__ not defined  include this code